# Macro to assign segments based on comparing value in cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to create a Macro that does the following:

Set first segment as 1

Checks if the abs difference between cell T3 and T4 is > 20, if it is assign segment number+1 in next column and move on to check T4 and T5.

If not keep segment number same as previous and compare T3 and T4+1 to determine if greater than 20.

This loop will keep running till all cells in column have been checked and a segment number has been assigned to each one.

The purpose is to determine if the number increases or decreases by 20 either accumulatively or in each cell it creates a new segment.

I can do this with if statements but can't get it to compare them accumulatively without a macro. Current macro shown below.

```
Sub segment()
 
'clears column and sets header as segment
ActiveSheet.Columns("P").Clear
Range("P1") = "Segment"
 
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim segment As Long
segment = 1
   
'checking the last cell in column 1
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Row
 
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
 
For i = 2 To (lastrow - 1) ' as first row is header
    For j = (i + 1) To lastrow
        If Abs(Cells(i, 15).Value - Cells(j, 15).Value) > Range("S2") Then
        Cells(i, 16).Value = segment ' putting segment numbers in column 16
        segment = segment + 1
        i = j - 1
        Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i
 
End Sub
```

Using the Macro above works however doesn't capture the following scenario with this number sequence:

187 - Start of Segment

187, 187, 175, 174, 174, 170, 178,

202, - THIS SHOULD BE A NEW SEGMENT AS GREATER THAN 20 BUT ISN'T

202,

162 - Next new Segment

Any ideas how to get it to also check each cell against the one above whilst also doing the steps above to account for accumulation?

Comment: Would be useful to see example before/after screenshot of the intended outcome

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints to help you fix it:

1. These two lines look like naturally one of them goes inside the `i` loop but outside the `j` loop, and the other goes inside the `j` loop within the `i` loop. However, you have both of them together in the `j` loop.

```
Cells(i, 16).Value = segment ' putting segment numbers in column 16
segment = segment + 1
```

This means, whenever you write a segment number, you also increment the segment. Based on your question it seems like you want to always write the segment (for every line) but only increment it if the difference >20.

2. These lines seem unusual for this application:

```
i = j - 1
Exit For
```

If you adjust for #1 above, you may be able to let the inner `j` loop finish each time.
In any event, resetting a loop counter like with `i = j - 1` is a bit odd and suggests there is a cleaner way to use these nested loops (refer #1 above).

Based on these 2 hints, I suspect you will be able to adjust your code to get the outcome you want.